# Implement Angular Caching conditionally on requests

Tags: angular, caching

Implement Caching in Angular with interceptor only for a few requests & not every request conditionally through a boolean.

I have been checking for online solutions about caching only few requests and not all. Sadly there's not any apt solution for this purpose.
Hence I decided to write one very simple Caching methodology to cache specific requests.

This can be done by below:

Create a cache.interceptor & cache.service like below and add it to the providers of app.module like so:

providers:[
CacheService,
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: CachingInterceptor, multi: true }]

CachingInterceptor code: The interceptor will only cache requests when it sees a particular header('cache-response') set by your services that make the http call.

import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

// Add the service we created in Step 1
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { CacheService } from './cache.service';

@Injectable()
export class CachingInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

constructor(private readonly cacheService: CacheService) {
  }

intercept(req: HttpRequest, next: HttpHandler): Observable> {
    // Don't cache if it's not a GET request
    if (req.method !== 'GET') {
      return next.handle(req);
    }

```
// delete cache if no header is set by service's method
if (!req.headers.get('cache-response')) {
  if (this.cacheService.cacheMap.get(req.urlWithParams)) {
    this.cacheService.cacheMap.delete(req.urlWithParams);
  }

  return next.handle(req);
}

// Checked if there is cached data for this URI
const cachedResponse = this.cacheService.getFromCache(req);
if (cachedResponse) {
  // In case of parallel requests to same URI,
  // return the request already in progress
  // otherwise return the last cached data
  return (cachedResponse instanceof Observable) ? cachedResponse : of(cachedResponse.clone());
}

// If the request of going through for first time
// then let the request proceed and cache the response
return next.handle(req)
    .pipe(tap(event => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            this.cacheService.addToCache(req, event);
        }
    }));
```

}
}

CacheService Code: This service is used to add/get from cache.

import { HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CacheService  {
  cacheMap = new Map(null);

getFromCache(req: HttpRequest): HttpResponse | undefined {
    const url = req.urlWithParams;
    const cached = this.cacheMap.get(url);

```
if (!cached) {
  return undefined;
}

return (this.cacheMap.get(url)).response;
```

}

addToCache(req: HttpRequest, response: HttpResponse): void {
    const url = req.url;
    const entry = { url, response, addedTime: Date.now() };
    this.cacheMap.set(url, entry);
  }
}

In your services: 
getMethod(int param1, cache = false): any {
    let headers: HttpHeaders;
    if (cache) {
      headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'cache-response': 'true' });
    }

```
return this.http.get(
  'http://apiUrl',
  { headers }
);
```

}

And thats it. You have an interceptor that cache's only requests that have a header set.

Answer (score 0):

Implement Caching in Angular with interceptor only for a few requests & not every request conditionally through a boolean.

I have been checking for online solutions about caching only few requests and not all. Sadly there's not any apt solution for this purpose.
Hence I decided to write one very simple Caching methodology to cache specific requests.

This can be done by below:

Create a cache.interceptor & cache.service like below and add it to the providers of app.module like so:

providers:[
CacheService,
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: CachingInterceptor, multi: true }]

CachingInterceptor code: The interceptor will only cache requests when it sees a particular header('cache-response') set by your services that make the http call.

import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

// Add the service we created in Step 1
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { CacheService } from './cache.service';

@Injectable()
export class CachingInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

constructor(private readonly cacheService: CacheService) {
  }

intercept(req: HttpRequest, next: HttpHandler): Observable> {
    // Don't cache if it's not a GET request
    if (req.method !== 'GET') {
      return next.handle(req);
    }

```
// delete cache if no header is set by service's method
if (!req.headers.get('cache-response')) {
  if (this.cacheService.cacheMap.get(req.urlWithParams)) {
    this.cacheService.cacheMap.delete(req.urlWithParams);
  }

  return next.handle(req);
}

// Checked if there is cached data for this URI
const cachedResponse = this.cacheService.getFromCache(req);
if (cachedResponse) {
  // In case of parallel requests to same URI,
  // return the request already in progress
  // otherwise return the last cached data
  return (cachedResponse instanceof Observable) ? cachedResponse : of(cachedResponse.clone());
}

// If the request of going through for first time
// then let the request proceed and cache the response
return next.handle(req)
    .pipe(tap(event => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            this.cacheService.addToCache(req, event);
        }
    }));
```

}
}

CacheService Code: This service is used to add/get from cache.

import { HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CacheService  {
  cacheMap = new Map(null);

getFromCache(req: HttpRequest): HttpResponse | undefined {
    const url = req.urlWithParams;
    const cached = this.cacheMap.get(url);

```
if (!cached) {
  return undefined;
}

return (this.cacheMap.get(url)).response;
```

}

addToCache(req: HttpRequest, response: HttpResponse): void {
    const url = req.url;
    const entry = { url, response, addedTime: Date.now() };
    this.cacheMap.set(url, entry);
  }
}

In your services: 
getMethod(int param1, cache = false): any {
    let headers: HttpHeaders;
    if (cache) {
      headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'cache-response': 'true' });
    }

```
return this.http.get(
  'http://apiUrl',
  { headers }
);
```

}

And thats it. You have an interceptor that cache's only requests that have a header set.